# Do objects iniside objects get stored in the stack or heap when it does not use the new keyword but the parent object is in the heap?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Basically, if I have class `A`, class A holds an instance of class `B` without using `new`, and I create an instance of class `A` using `new`. Does the instance of class `B` inside of class `A` get stored in the stack or heap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `B` is part of the `A`. So wherever the `A` is stored (be it stack, heap or whatever), that is, by definition, where the `B` is stored.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the new keyword, an object gets created on the heap. Without the new keyword, it would be created on the stack.

To elaborate, Your object to Class A is created using new keyword to which a pointer is returned. The Object of Class A gets created on the heap with the pointer to it on stack. Now, in your Object of Class A, you are creating an Object of Class B without using new keyword. If Object of Class B is inside a function, then it gets stored on the stack. Else if Object B is declared at class scope then it will be on heap.

Comment: My question was whether or not it would be stored in the stack without the keyword `new` if the parent object wasn't in the stack.

Comment: Without `new` it might not be "on the stack", there is also thread-local storage and static storage.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I think for that we have to use the `thread_local` and `static` keywords which is not mentioned in the question

Comment: @Abhishek not if the object is at file scope. The question didn't even mention creating A without using `new`